# Can't create a file through symbolic link

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions

I have a directory that goes like this:

```
    drwxrwxrwx  6 www-data www-data     4096 Jun  8 10:21 ./
    drwxr-xr-x 31 user1    user1        4096 Jun  8 10:40 ../
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data       66 Jun  8 10:21 archive -> /media/user1/7f62b5e4-4fe7-43c2-b0d0-8dad6e5a2381/archive/
```

I try to create a file with `touch` in the symbolic link with the user www-data. I get this error:

```
$ sudo -u www-data touch archive/myfile
touch: cannot touch ‘archive/myfile’: Permission denied
```

The root directory and the archive directory are chmod 777.

But this works correctly

```
$ touch archive/myfile
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the probleme by mounting the hard disk pointed by the symbolic link. In fact, media/ is the path set by default so you need to mount the disk to set a valid path. Here is a link were you can find how to automatically mount a hard disk : [InstallingANewHardDrive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive)

Answer (score 1):

The permissions or owner of `/media/user1/7f62b5e4-4fe7-43c2-b0d0-8dad6e5a2381/archive/` are apparently different from the symbolic link.

Do `ls -ld /media/user1/7f62b5e4-4fe7-43c2-b0d0-8dad6e5a2381/archive/` to see their current values, and correct them accordingly with `chmod` and `chown`.

Comment: Here is what I get:

    `drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  8 11:43 /media/user1/7f62b5e4-4fe7-43c2-b0d0-8dad6e5a2381/archive/`

See normaly the user www-data has the right to write in the directory